# How to incluse an external .js file to page in HtmlUnit?

Tags: javascript, html, htmlunit

I want to run an external .js file after page loaded in HtmlUnit. How to incluse an external .js file to page in HtmlUnit?

Thanks,
Huy

Answer (score 1):

this seems to be a common question. One answer that was found was just to wait.

[HtmlUnit doesn't load externally referenced javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848398/htmlunit-doesnt-load-externally-referenced-javascript)